# Product View does not show for Anonymous user

Tags: commerce

I would like to use a view to display products in front page. So, in the view 'Products (Commerce Product)' i created separate block view 'My Products Block'. This view is added to the region in Block section and then rendered in the front page:

```
print render($page['region_containing_product_view']);
```

This displays products fine if logged in as admin but not for anonymous users. For anonymous users it shows:

```
No products have been created yet. Add a product.
```

I have updated the permissions for my custom view to 'Access:Role | anonymous user' but it still doesn't show the products. How come? what am i doing wrong?

Thank You
p.s. Drupal 7, Commerce module

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out for every product type created there is permissions that need to be enabled for every user roles including anonymous users

'people-permissions-roles'

Comment: bum...couple months later again wasted time on this. So, if you create view from entity of type products, make sure to enable permission 'View any product of any type' for anonymous user other wise the view will not display the products for site visitors

Comment: That's bummer because Drupal says it has security implications and should only be displayed to trusted users.